# HTML select ONE zip file OR multiple other files

Tags: html, file-upload

I would like that a user can either select

- one Zip File OR
- multiple PDFs and pictures (like PNG, ...)

So when a user selects a Zip File, he/she is not allowed to select other PDF or pictures.
When a user selects a PDF, he/she is allowed to select other PDFs or pictures.

This is my input field:

```
<input type="file" name="myfile" id="file-to-upload" multiple/>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please upload a zip file 
<input type="file" name="myfile" id="zipfile-to-upload" />
or separate image file(s)
<input type="file" name="myfile" id="file-to-upload" multiple/>
```

Comment: So I have to have two buttons? Thanks

Comment: You do not HAVE to, but that is the fastest and most obvious solution

Comment: Thanks a lot! That´s anouth for my solution but if anyone knows, how to solve this with one button, please feel free to answer becaue I am interested :)